# consoleTVs charts 6.x color

Tags: laravel, charts, colors

How to set color in laravel consoletvs charts V6.x?

```
    $chart = new SampleChart;
    $chart->displayAxes(false);
    $chart->dataset('W1', 'pie', array('10','80','10'));
```

->colors() doesn't work! Think it's in the old Version. 
Currently all values are grey.

Answer (score 8):

Try the following code

```
    $chart = new SampleChart;
    $chart->labels(['One', 'Two', 'Three']);

    $dataset = $chart->dataset('My dataset', 'pie', array('10','80','10'));
    $dataset->backgroundColor(collect(['#7158e2','#3ae374', '#ff3838']));
    $dataset->color(collect(['#7d5fff','#32ff7e', '#ff4d4d']));

    return view('view', compact('chart'));
```

based on [repository](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/blob/master/src/Features/Chartjs/Dataset.php) backgroundColor and color are collections so you can pass variables in that way.

Comment: it worked fro me i am working on `laravel 5.7.28`  and with `consoletvs/charts 6.3` and it is working fine for me

Answer (score 2):

This woks fine for me!

```
 $chart = new SampleChart;    
        $chart->title("First Response Time");        
        $chart->labels(['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']);
        $chart->dataset('My dataset 1', 'bar', [1, 2, 3, 10]);   
        $chart->dataset('My dataset 2', 'bar', [4, 3, 2, 10])->backgroundcolor('green');                               
        $chart->height(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's on the Dataset object, if you look at the Github [repository](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/blob/master/src/Features/Chartjs/Dataset.php) you can see that Dataset trait has color and backgroundColor method so you can try to call color method directly on the dataset object.

As you can see in [this class](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/blob/master/src/Classes/BaseChart.php) when you call dataset method, it creates a new Dataset and return it.

So you can test the given code :

```
$chart = new SampleChart;
$chart->displayAxes(false);
$chart->dataset('W1', 'pie', array('10','80','10'))->color(...);
```

or

```
$chart = new SampleChart;
$chart->displayAxes(false);
$dataset = $chart->dataset('W1', 'pie', array('10','80','10'));
$dataset->color(...);
```

I hopes it helps you.